# Avoid having double underscores in helper method while mapping a module to the root of a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a namespace `Foo` (directory `/app/controllers/foo`) and a controller `Foo::BarController` within it (directory `/app/controllers/foo/bar_controller.rb`).

I want to route the resources of `Foo::BarController` to the root of `Foo`. I tried this in the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :foo do
    scope module: :bar do
      resources ""
    end
  end
end
```

which gives the mapping between paths and controller methods as I wanted. However, as for the helper method for `GET /foo(:format)`, I get

```
foo__index_path
```

I want to get rid of the extra underscore to get

```
foo_index_path
```

How can I do it?

Since I have other controllers within the namespace `foo`, if possible, I want to surround the whole routes specification with a `namespace :foo do ... end` block as I did above, and avoid handling the root case as a special one.

---

Is this behavior of Rails generating a helper method with consecutive underscores intended, or can I call it a bug?

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistency. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double underscore is because that's where the resource name would go, usually. Since your resource name is `""`, you end up with `foo__index` as the route helper.

Instead you may want to change your route file to

```
scope :foo, module: :foo do
  resources :bar, path: "", as: :foo
  resources :baz # just to show what happens to the other routes
end
```

and then `rake routes` gives you

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
foo_index GET    /foo(.:format)              foo/bar#index
          POST   /foo(.:format)              foo/bar#create
  new_foo GET    /foo/new(.:format)          foo/bar#new
 edit_foo GET    /foo/:id/edit(.:format)     foo/bar#edit
      foo GET    /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#show
          PATCH  /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#update
          PUT    /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#update
          DELETE /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#destroy
baz_index GET    /foo/baz(.:format)          foo/baz#index
          POST   /foo/baz(.:format)          foo/baz#create
  new_baz GET    /foo/baz/new(.:format)      foo/baz#new
 edit_baz GET    /foo/baz/:id/edit(.:format) foo/baz#edit
      baz GET    /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#show
          PATCH  /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#update
          PUT    /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#update
          DELETE /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#destroy
```

instead of

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern             Controller#Action
foo__index GET    /foo(.:format)          foo/bar/#index
           POST   /foo(.:format)          foo/bar/#create
   new_foo GET    /foo/new(.:format)      foo/bar/#new
  edit_foo GET    /foo/:id/edit(.:format) foo/bar/#edit
       foo GET    /foo/:id(.:format)      foo/bar/#show
           PATCH  /foo/:id(.:format)      foo/bar/#update
           PUT    /foo/:id(.:format)      foo/bar/#update
           DELETE /foo/:id(.:format)      foo/bar/#destroy
```

with your current set up, which I believe would throw an error of some kind (I get uninitialized constant `Foo::Bar` using your initial setup with a scope).

If you then want other resources nested within the `Foo` namespace to retain the `foo_baz_index` instead of `baz_index` you can put those in another scope

```
scope :foo, module: :foo do
  resources :bar, path: "/", as: :foo

  scope as: :foo do
    resources :baz
  end
end
```

which yields

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
    foo_index GET    /foo(.:format)              foo/bar#index
              POST   /foo(.:format)              foo/bar#create
      new_foo GET    /foo/new(.:format)          foo/bar#new
     edit_foo GET    /foo/:id/edit(.:format)     foo/bar#edit
          foo GET    /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#show
              PATCH  /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#update
              PUT    /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#update
              DELETE /foo/:id(.:format)          foo/bar#destroy
foo_baz_index GET    /foo/baz(.:format)          foo/baz#index
              POST   /foo/baz(.:format)          foo/baz#create
  new_foo_baz GET    /foo/baz/new(.:format)      foo/baz#new
 edit_foo_baz GET    /foo/baz/:id/edit(.:format) foo/baz#edit
      foo_baz GET    /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#show
              PATCH  /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#update
              PUT    /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#update
              DELETE /foo/baz/:id(.:format)      foo/baz#destroy
```

Comment: But then, I will get `foo_bar_index_path`, whereas I wanted `foo_index_path`.